# OpsHub - Import UserList error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

My migration fails on the user mapping task with the following error :

```
OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1412109029732 ALM TFS 1412109029738, due to (301)Moved Permanently
```

I am running on **v1.0.1.006.**

Thanks for help

Comment: One possible reason could be that your TFS instance was migrated in the past, during which the URL was also changed. It is quite possible that the redirection is having some issues with the WCF Proxy OpsHub's Utility uses.

Please send us the logs created by the utility from the following location "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" to ovsmu@opshub.com and we can deduce the actual reason of this error.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine that you are using the utility on behind a proxy then this issue will come, new version will be available on first week of November.

Comment: release new version  1.0.1.008, try this one from visualstudiogallery.